# SQL SERVER,¿Alguna manera de hacer SUM(COUNT())?

Tags: sql-server, date

Tengo una duda acerca de este query. Como pueden notar hay 3 columnas.

ALUMNO: Nombres de los alumnos

LUGAR: Lugar donde asistieron

FECHA_ASIS: Numero de dias que asistieron a su *lugar* respectivo.

```
SELECT ALUMNO,LUGAR,COUNT(DISTINCT(FECHA_ASIS)) AS GUARDIAS                
FROM TABLA AS AL
WHERE ESTADO='A' AND TIEMPO=035 GROUP BY ALUMNO,LUGAR
```

**SALIDA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, como notan hay alumnos que asistieron a varios lugares, mi duda/problema es que quisiera obtener el numero total de días asistidos de cada alumno.

```
SELECT ALUMNO,COUNT(DISTINCT(FECHA_ASIS)) AS GUARDIAS                
FROM TABLA AS AL
WHERE ESTADO='A' AND TIEMPO=035 GROUP BY ALUMNO
```

**SALIDA**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado adicionarle:

```
SELECT ALUMNO,SUM(COUNT(FECHA_ASIS))
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error:
*No es posible usar una función de agregado con una expresión que contiene un agregado o una subconsulta.*

**RESULTADO QUE QUIERO LLEGAR**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en dos pasos: Ya tienes la consulta que suma por alumno y lugar, ahora puedes hacer una consulta que sume por alumno tomando el resultado de la anterior como datos:

```
SELECT SUB.ALUMNO, COUNT(SUB.GUARDIAS)
FROM (SELECT ALUMNO, LUGAR, COUNT(DISTINCT(FECHA_ASIS)) AS GUARDIAS                
      FROM TABLA AS AL
      WHERE ESTADO='A' AND TIEMPO=035 GROUP BY ALUMNO,LUGAR) as SUB
GROUP BY SUB.ALUMNO
```

Comment: Hola @Pablo, no reconoce la columna ALUMNO, no puede ser enlazado. Gracias

Comment: Excelente, gracias por editarlo, entiendo mejor,muchas gracias @Pablo.

Answer (score 1):

Solo usa el SUM sin el count y lo agrupas por Alumno

```
SELECT ALUMNO,SUM(FECHA_ASIS) 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY ALUMNO
```

Eso es para que la consulta sume los valores de la columna FECHA_ASIS y si el alumno es igual pero FECHA_ASIS diferente se usa el GROUP BY, para agruparlos en un solo valor.

**UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO #TABLATEMPORAL
SELECT ALUMNO, LUGAR, COUNT(DISTINCT(FECHA_ASIS)) AS GUARDIAS                
FROM TABLA AS AL
WHERE ESTADO='A' AND TIEMPO=035 GROUP BY ALUMNO,LUGAR

SELECT ALUMNO, SUM(GUARDIAS)
FROM #TABLATEMPORAL
GROUP BY ALUMNO
```

O también como la otra respuesta, usando subconsultas, como se te haga mas sencillo

Comment: Hola @TheVicshow, lo he intentado con anterioridad y obtengo este resultado: El tipo de datos datetime del operando no es válido para el operador sum.

Comment: aaaah, es que no es integer, cierto es fecha, entonces te recomiendo usar tablas temporales, dejame te escribo un ejemplo

Comment: Gracias @TheVicShow, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta, gracias por tomarte el tiempo.